Why does the reported memory usage of a systemd service differ from the sum of memory usage in top?
I am running a systemd service named agent.service on my Linux system, and I've noticed a discrepancy between the reported memory usage of the service and the combined memory usage of its constituent processes as observed in the top command.
Here is the relevant output from systemctl status agent.service:
● agent.service -  Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-04-10 16:01:44 +07; 15min ago
   Main PID: 151812 (agent)
      Tasks: 58 (limit: 18691)
     Memory: 198.3M (limit: 200.0M)
     CGroup: /system.slice/agent.service
             ├─151812 /root/agent --opampServer=false --nodeExporter=true
             ├─151822 /root/agent --opampServer=false --nodeExporter=true
             ├─151830 /proc/151822/fd/3
             └─151839 /proc/151822/fd/8 --config /tmp/otelcol/otelcol-config.yaml


Additionally, here is the output from the top command, showing the memory usage (RES column) of specific processes associated with agent.service:
PID    USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
134031 root      20   0 1491940 261288 260052 S   0.0   1.6   0:00.77 vcoagent
134050 root      20   0 1466668 146340 112240 S   0.0   0.9   0:06.04 8 
151830 root      20   0 1241644  17628  10732 S   0.0   0.1   0:01.18 3
151812 root      20   0 1639660   7964   6944 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.71 vcoagent

The RES column in top represents the resident (non-swapped) memory usage of each process. As seen in the top output, the RES values of processes 134031, 134050, 151830, and 151812do not appear to sum up to the reported memory usage (198.3M) of the agent.service.
My question is: Why is there a discrepancy between the reported memory usage of the agent.service (198.3M) and the combined resident memory (RES) usage of its constituent processes in top? Does systemd account for memory usage differently than what top displays for individual processes?
I would appreciate any insights or clarifications on how systemd calculates and reports memory usage for services compared to how individual process memory (RES) is displayed in tools like top.
Thank you!
I want to know why does the reported memory usage of a systemd service differ from the sum of memory usage in top?

Pages assigned to a process consist of both pages unique to that process and pages shared with other processes.
The service's memory use number is probably sourced from the cgroup, which likely does not double count most shared pages, where adding up the RSS in top will certainly double count shared pages.
Additionally, some of the shared pages will be shared with things outside the cgroup, and these may or may not be counted in the cgroup total.
On top of that, any number you see will be a snapshot in time, as the memory use can vary drastically over time, and pulling a synchronized sample across multiple processes would incur lots of overhead so it is not done.  Consequently, there will be sampling errors.
In short, the memory numbers in these places is an estimate at best, and the actual memory use is a lot more complicated than a single number (or even the 3-4 numbers listed in top) can express.
The per process memory use numbers exposed by the kernel are useful in determining which process is using the most memory, and may be useful in estimating memory needed and other performance related uses.  But it is not useful for counting total memory used in the system.  Those numbers are found elsewhere, and are also complicated and have lots of overlaps.  wc -l /proc/meminfo lists 55 entries in the current kernel I am using.
